# Can't make the navbar go 0px on top padding.

Tags: html, css, navbar, padding

I'm new to HTML and CSS, and now I'm having problem with the padding on my navbar, I can't make it "reach" the top, there's a space between the navbar and the top of the site that i can't get rid of.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Projekt 2</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="p2.css">
</head>  
<body>
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
padding-top: 0px;
font-family: monospace;
}

.nav {
background-color: dimgrey;
color: white;
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
```

Now here is the problem, I cant seem to get rid of the white space above the navigation bar, although I've put the padding to 0px. I've tried changing the pixel around, I've tried with the padding-top attribute, but nothin seems to help, any help is appreciated, thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me2YB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, adding **margin-top: 0px;** to your **.nav**

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
padding-top: 0px;
font-family: monospace;
}

.nav {
background-color: dimgrey;
color: white;
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

UL tags have margins by default. You simply need to remove them.

```
.nav {
  background-color: dimgrey;
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   .nav{ 
      padding-top:0px;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps there is something else in your linked stylesheet which is overriding the CSS you included in your post?

Try adding !important and see if that fixes things. Doing this essentially tells the browser to use this above any others...

E.g. Padding-top: 0 !important;

You could also have either padding or a margin set for the li or a elements. Check those things too.